# Yii and Vue2 CORS enable. Server responds to preflight OPTIONS request with 404 error

Tags: php, yii, vuejs2, cors, preflight

I have got two boiler-plate egxamples.

First is Yii2 from this:
https://github.com/m-alfan/api-yii2-boilerplate

Second is Vue2: 
https://github.com/cornflourblue/vue-vuex-registration-login-example

I've deployed first on my Apache2 server with http://basic.vue2 domain, client runs on second domain by npm server.

The problem is that when I send POST request i got 404 Options

https://ibb.co/r6ctBHr

https://ibb.co/0mmQ44m

https://ibb.co/BZM4d7Y

[image]

[image]

[image]

Somebody knows how to configure CORS for Yii? I tried add cors into GuestController.php behaviors() but it failed to.

Answer (score 1):

404 could be a wrong urlManager rules or a missing, you start from the here.

Comment: It working when i send request from swagger. So I think that urlManager is correct

Answer (score 0):

Configure CORS for yii and please ensure that the `OPTIONS` action/verb is allowed.

See also the docs here: [CORS config](https://github.com/sirinibin/Yii2-RESTful-API-with-OAuth2/blob/master/backend/controllers/RestController.php)

i.e:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            'Origin' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            'Allow' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => null,
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => []
        ]

    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```